Как сделать так, чтобы несколько объектов с материалом, использующим режим наложения Multiply, не перекрывались?
Есть объекты с кровью на которых висит прозрачный материал Universal Render Pipeline/Unlit
и у этого материала я врубил режим наложения multiply, так как мне показалось такое наложение крови красивым. Вот скриншот материала:

Если крови много в одном месте то она начинает затемнятся так как показано на здесь:

А мне надо, чтобы при большом количестве крови сохранялся красный цвет, как слева на скриншоте. Я облазил весь интернет в поисках решения но ничего не нашел или может быть я чего-то не понимаю. Подскажите мне, пожалуйста, как это исправить?
P.S. Я хочу чтобы режим наложения оставался multiply или похожим

Ты хочешь взаимо исключающие вещи.
